# Let $n$ be an integer. Then $n^2 + 7$ is odd only if $n$ is even.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I want to prove this proposition but unsure how to start it.
I started off with:

> Assume $n$ is even, then $n^2$ is even.
>   When $even + odd = odd$.
>   Thus, $n^2 + 7$ is odd only if $n$ is even.

Does this make sense for a proof? If not how could I improve it?

Comment: Prove by contrapositive.

Comment: If $n$ is even your proof is finished since then even plus odd is odd.

Comment: You're proving "only if". Start by assuming $n$ is odd, and show $n^2 + 7$ is even.

Comment: @Nathaniel Mayer Does that use contrappositive?

Comment: @Any Yes it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n^2 + 7$ is odd $\Leftrightarrow$ $n^2$ is even $\Leftrightarrow$ $n$ is even

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is odd, $n^2$ is odd ($(2k+1)^2 = 4(k^2+k)+1$), and odd+odd is even.

If $n$ is even, $n^2$ is obviously even (divisible by $n$, which is even), and even+odd is odd.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use congruences modulo $2$.